# Iterating over a ajax-returned list with $.each - Element is always null

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have the following C# code in my API-controller:

```
public JsonResult GetProjects()
{
    List<ProjectItem> list = ProjectItem.Get();
    return new JsonResult() {Data = list, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet};;
}
```

I stepped through this code and found out that the list contains elements on this point. But in the Ajax-call I'm calling the code I try to iterate over the single elements with Jquery and try to use them. But the elements are always null.

Typescript Ajax-Call:

```
 $.ajax({
            url: "/api//MyControllerName",
            type: "GET",
            cache:false,
            dataType: "json",
            success: (result) => {
                base.projects.removeAll();

                $.each(result, (index: number, element: any) => {

                    //Here the element from the list should be used, but it is always null   
                    });
                });
            }
        });
```

What is wrong with this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, found the solution to my problem myself:

I tried to iterate over the result, but I have to iterate over the Data-Property of the result.

With this code it works:

```
$.each(result.Data, (index: number, element: any) => {
    //Element is defined
}
```